# Is there a standard component free notation for this contraction?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

Let $(M,\nabla)$ be a smooth manifold with an affine connection $\nabla$ on $TM$. Very often we find the following operation being performed in a coordinate basis $\nabla_\alpha T^{\alpha\beta}$. One example is the conservation condition in General Relativity, which is expressed as

$$\nabla_\alpha T^{\alpha\beta}=0.$$

Here $\nabla_\alpha$ denotes the covariant derivative with respect to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}$ as it is usually done.

Now, is there any other standard notation to mean this operation without involving components?

I mean, there's nothing wrong with this one, I'm quite fine with it. It is just curiosity.

One notation I thought was $\nabla\cdot T$, but this has a problem, since it is not clear whether we are contracting with the first or second index of $T$.

Comment: In Barrett Oneill's Semi-Riemannian Geometry, Chapter 2, Section 4 he discusses contractions. I suspect this is what you are looking for. I had a course where this was done, that is contractions in a coordinate free set-up. I found it rather unfun as a student, it really clouded things for me. But, maybe I'd appreciate it more now. I think the "hook" is an example of what you're looking for, the X hook $\alpha$ is the evaluation of the one-form with the vector field.

Comment: Often the notation $div T$ is used.